# Find center of a fixed-width bounding box

Tags: math, geometry

Given a collection of points, I'd like to find the center of a bounding box (fixed-length and width) that maximizes the number of points within said box. I'm at a loss for an efficient way to do this.

Comment: How efficient do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algorithm with complexity O(N^2*logN) (I hope that better one exists):

**Edit**: [article exploiting interval trees](http://ac.els-cdn.com/089812219500029X/1-s2.0-089812219500029X-main.pdf?_tid=3059d110-c821-11e5-9e85-00000aab0f26&acdnat=1454248237_39042f1ed5a069de5bb451c8e884f73c) claims O(NlogN) complexity

Sort data array A by X coordinate.
Scan A with sweep line left to right.
For every point in A get `LeftX = A[k].X` - left coordinate of vertical band, find the rightmost coordinate of vertical band `RightX = LeftX + Width`.
Copy points inside the band to another array B.

Sort B by Y-coordinate.
Scan B width sweep line top to down. 
For every point B[i] get `TopY = B[i].Y` - top coordinate of rectangle, calculate `BottomY = TopY + Height`.
Use binary search in B:
B[j] is the last bottom point in B with `B[j].Y <= BottomY`.

Find number of points in the current rectangle:
Number of points is `N(k, i) = j - i + 1`

Check whether `N(k, i)` is maximum among others

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a difficult problem, here is my idea:
Hold a graph, each node holds a rectangle and a subset of points. the rectangle defines the area where placing the bounding box in would overlap all the points in the subset.

To build the graph:
Start with a root node holding the empty set and the rect `[top:-inf, bottom:inf, left:-inf, right:inf]`

For each point in the tree call this recursive function with the root node (pseudo code):

```
function addPoint(node, point)
    // check that you didn't already try to add this point to this node
    // node.tested can be a hash set
    if(node.tested contains point)
        return        
    node.tested.add(point)

    newRect = node.rect.intersectWith(boundingBoxAround(point))
    // if the bounding box around the point does not intersect the rectangle, return
    if(newRect is invalid) // rect is invalid if right<left or bottom<top
        return

    node.addChild(new node(newRect, node.pointSet U {point}) 

    for each child of node
        addPoint(child, point)
```

Now you just pick the node with the largest subset, you can keep track of that when building the graph so you don't need to run through the graph again.

I hope my idea is clear, let me know if I can explain it better.